Can't Inspect variables in Visual Studio 2022
I can't inspect variables in Visual Studio 2022. Steps to reproduce:
1 - Get a new computer with Windows 10
2 - Install VS2017 Professional.
3 - Install VS2022 Professional.
4 - Menu->File->New->Project and create a new ASP.Net Core Web API application.
5 - Press F10 to step into the start of the application. Step through the first few instructions to initialize a few variables. Hover over one and you get nothing. Do a quick watch on one and you get the error "Internal error in the expression evaluator."
Now, chances are good it's not going to do this to you, but it's doing it to me. The solutions here don't apply since VS2022 doesn't have the "Legacy C#" option and it's a fresh install, so everything already is defaulted.
What are possible solutions?

This question is similar to: Visual Studio 2022 - Values while debugging (DataTips) not working while hover on properties c#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are a couple of answers in that link above that pertain specifically to VS 2022. I will say, I'm not confident you'll find a solution in that post, as it seems like there is more than one thing that can cause the error. If you don't find a solution there, just update your question stating so.

I don't have VS 2022 on this computer, so I can't check for myself, but also try Managed Compatibility Mode if you have it.

"Managed Compatibility Mode" isn't a setting in VS2022.

Hi @Argle, sorry for ignoring a fresh install. I followed your steps but can't reproduce the same issue at my side. Could you please share code snippets and screenshots of  error message to help us  better understand your scenario?

Sure. You can get a code snippet if you do my step #4. It's the stock program created by VS2022. Here's the started app with no hover showing: https://i.imgur.com/rgXLnqF.png and what happens if I do a quick watch instead: https://i.imgur.com/whXxZkz.png (I inserted foo at line 12 just for the heck of it but it won't show either.)

It's a weird behavior. Quick watch is working well in my VS17.10.4.
Test result. What is the version of your VS2022 installed on your machine? Will the value display if you click Reevaluate button?

Using VS17.10.4. Reevaluate does nothing.

I note that this problem has been reported on Microsoft's support site. In usual Microsoft fashion, the reply borders on "it works on our end. question closed."

Is this issue specific to the Project ASP.Net Core Web API or all your project templates? Besides did you any error message during install VS2022? If yes, please consider try to repair your installation from VS Installer.

While I haven't tried all templates, it's failed on several I have tried. Those have been C# Windows form, console app and Web API. I haven't yet tried a C++ template because I hadn't installed that option. It's been repaired and re-installed several times.

Followup: I modified VS2022 and installed C++. I built the "hello world" app and added a local variable. Stepped into the code and I could inspect the local variable without issue. So the inspection problem seems exclusive to C#.

If it's convenient for you, I suggest you test it on another machine.
If it can be reproduced on another machine, it is recommended that you re-report the issue on the MS forum.
If not, there maybe some problems with your local environment, and I recommend that you use InstallCleanup.exe`tool to completely remove all installed instances and reinstall the latest version.

Dou Xu, there are probably 50 computers within 50 feet of me with VS2022 and none with the same problem. FWIW, the computer I had prior to the new one had the same problem, so clearly it's "something" installed. The problem has been reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/internal-error-in-the-expression-evaluat/10678389?sort=active&viewtype=all

I ran InstallCleanup.exe and then reinstalled VS2022. That didn't fix the problem. I had a co-worker suggest rolling back to VS2022 17.6. She said her bit of digging said that it's new with 17.8/17.10. I tried this, but was left with the same problem.

Just suggestions: 1 use devenv /Log NameOfLogFile to log all activity to the log file and check whether there are error messages . 2  run Collect.exe tool to generate vslogs.zip files and check if there are any installation errors. 3. Add a new comment on this MS forum ticketand ask if there are any updates.
